# Building a web app with angular 2+ and Spring boot from scratch?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web-applications

I am supposed to build a web app for my student project. The frontend should be made with Angular 2 framework, and backend with Spring boot. 
I have been searching for free tutorials/courses but haven't been successful yet.

I'm having trouble starting, i have a fairly basic knowledge of the angular framework (html,css,bootstrap,javascript,typescript), and a solid knowledge of the Java programming language but i just can't find the right tutorials/courses that connects the two.

Do you have any recommendations or tutorials on how to build the app from scratch with Angular and Spring Boot? Or a list of things i need to learn to make the web-app besides that?
Overall, i just need some help with starting to create the web app, because i never made one. 20mins long Youtube videos are not much helpful because they don't cover creating the app from scratch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you planning to use angular spring boot together in a simple project or as a 2 separate projects?

Comment: you can use this post https://dzone.com/articles/angular-2-and-spring-boot-development-environment

Comment: @PratapA.K i am planning to use both of them in a single project. The project is a web app for recycling in my country. So it must be dynamic, where users will be able to filter their search by City, and there must be a back end part (that's why i need spring boot) that will hold my data. So, front end-Angular, back end-spring boot.

MostafaMashayekhi thanks, that helped me a lot with the setup part. I just needed some help with starting.